# Nano on server ignores certain syntax coloring

Tags: syntax-highlighting, nano

I'm using `nano` on a server via ssh; on that system, `nano` doesn't have syntax color enabled by default. So I copied these [nanosyntax](http://code.google.com/p/nanosyntax/) files (*for alternative, see also [@CraigBarnes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11107296/277826)*) on the server, and had set up `~/.nanorc` as:

```
include "~/nanosyntax/syntax-nanorc/php.nanorc"
include "~/nanosyntax/syntax-nanorc/php2.nanorc"
include "~/nanosyntax/syntax-nanorc/sh.nanorc"
include "~/nanosyntax/syntax-nanorc/python.nanorc"
include "~/nanosyntax/syntax-nanorc/html.nanorc"
include "~/nanosyntax/syntax-nanorc/perl.nanorc"
include "~/nanosyntax/syntax-nanorc/ruby.nanorc"
include "~/nanosyntax/syntax-nanorc/js.nanorc"
```

Now, this is the thing; if I just call:

```
nano somefile.php
```

... no `php` syntax coloring is done. If I try to force:

```
nano --syntax=php somefile.php
```

... still no syntax coloring (shown as plain text). However, if I do:

```
nano ~/.nanorc
```

... then I **do** get syntax coloring (that corresponds to `.nanorc` type file) ?!

So obviously, syntax coloring as such works (i.e. shell and `nano` are capable of it) - except, it seems to be ignored for some languages, like in this case `php` ?!

So, does anyone know what is going on - and how could I get syntax coloring also for `php` files?

Thanks,
Cheers!

Comment: Are you sure that those files are in the right directories and readable by the nano process?

Comment: Thanks for comment, @Noufal Ibrahim - as far as I can see, all those files have `rrr` attributes, and should be fine; besides, the coloring for `nanorc` would be apparently in `~/nanosyntax/syntax-nanorc/nanorc.nanorc` - and that one, seemingly, works ?!

Comment: I have the same issue, and the permissions for all files in `/usr/shared/nano/` are exactly the same. As original poster, my .nanorc works too, but nothing else works. CentOS 7.6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem, and I fiddled around a bit with the includes to find the error. Surprisingly, turns out that changing the inclusion order fixed the issue:

This works:

```
include "~/.nano/nanorc.nanorc"
include "~/.nano/sh.nanorc"
# more includes...
```

This fails to highlight sh files:

```
include "~/.nano/sh.nanorc"
include "~/.nano/nanorc.nanorc"
# more includes...
```

So I guess it's probably a bug (in nano 2.2.2; worked fine in nano 2.1.7)

Answer (score 1):

Hm... well, it seems there has been an upgrade on that server I was using; originally, `nano` didn't have syntax coloring by default, which is why I used my own separate `~/.nanorc`.

Now, however, on the upgraded server, `nano` seems to work with php syntax coloring by default - and me having my own separate `~/.nanorc` seems to have conflicted; because, once I commented all the entries in the private `~/.nanorc` (with an `#`), php syntax coloring was back!!

Whowouldathunkit ?! :)
Cheers!

---

EDIT: Just to add a couple of notes about nano:

As noted above, syntax coloring is forced with `--syntax` switch; to see which syntaxes are available:

```
grep 'include' /etc/nanorc |       # find lines containing 'include' in nanorc
  grep -v '^#' |                   # don't process lines that start with '#'
    sed 's_.*/\(.*\)\.nanorc"_\1_' # extract plain filenames
```

Result of this command is something like:

```
nanorc
c
css
debian
gentoo
html
...
```

So to force "nanorc" syntax coloring, you use:

```
nano --syntax=nanorc /usr/share/nano/nanorc.nanorc
```

.. or forcing "bash" shell script syntax coloring (especially useful with `bashrc`) would be:

```
nano --syntax=sh ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: --syntax switch is what i need

Answer (score 1):

Those "nanosyntax" files on Google Code are nearly as bad as ones that come with nano by default.

nano's highlighting engine is more basic than something with nested contexts (e.g. GtkSourceView) but you don't have to settle for crappy highlighting:

https://github.com/craigbarnes/nanorc

Comment: Many thanks for sharing, @CraigBarnes - cheers! (added link to this post in the OP too)

Comment: Dead link of GitHub